# Why won't openSystemURL on watchOS2 won't open tel: urls

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to dial a number in my watchOS 2 application using the `openSystemURL` with a `tel:` URL method:

```
let extent = WKExtension.sharedExtension()
extent.openSystemURL(NSURL(string: "tel:1-408-555-1212")!)
```

This does not do anything, however when I use the `sms:` URL it works just as it should if I were to send an sms message.

It explicitly says in the documentation that opening `tel:` URLS is very well possible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf) "Note: Phone links are supported on iOS only."

Comment: Are you in the simulator by chance?

Comment: I am using an actual Apple watch

Comment: @A-Live The URL Documentation is outdated for watchOS 2 beta

Comment: Yes it seems like it hasn't been updated specifically for watchos, however it doesn't automatically mean that the note about the scheme being supported only by iOs is irrelevant. Same goes for sms scheme, the fact that it works is simply a matter of both options being possible.

Comment: @A-Live It must be a bug maybe in beta 4 it will be fixed

Comment: This is no know bug in current beta.  See forum post here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4385

Comment: @rmp that forum doesn't prove anything it states that making phone calls on simulator doesn't work, however I am using an actual Apple watch and it still does not work.

Comment: Read the entire thread, especially the last post by an Apple moderator : "In addition, there's a known issue where using this API to start a phone call also isn't working on device. "

Comment: @rmp ok... Isn't that a bug?

Comment: Yes, that's what the Apple moderator is saying and that it is already know, meaning it's already been reported as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This API is now working in **watchOS 2 beta 5**